# XAML based on Conditions (IF/Then View)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

So I am trying to build a usercontrol that may or may not have children to it. I know C# but still learning a lot about the XAML side of things.

What I want to do is something like:

IF Children.Count > 0 then Create TreeView
ELSE Create Label

I know how to create a single view but I don't know how to create a view based on conditions like this. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Use styles and triggers.

Comment: can you post your actual code?

Comment: I was just looking for some way to "if collection has children draw this state" if not "draw this state". I think it is the case of overthinking this :). Seeing what the proper and practical way of doing this would be in Xaml.

Answer (score 0):

A "no Code questions" is rewarded by a "no Code answer"  ;o)

Put a treeview in your "usercontrol" 
Put your Label in your "usercontrol"

Bind the Visibility property of both to your Collection Holding your "Children".

Create two different (or one parametrized)  IValueConverter-Implementing-Converter and use that as "Converter=...." in your Binding.

Make the one converter return Visibility.Hidden when you have less than two childs, make the second return Visibility.Hidden when you have zero or one child.

Put the correct Converter to each of your Bindings so the Label is Hidden when more than one Child is in your Collection and the TreeView is hidden if less than two Childs are in the Collection.

Rethink Building a full fleshed "usercontrol" for this ...